# difficult zooming behavior with checkbox in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am attempting to implement a nice checkbox styling that replaces the default, and it works fine in all browsers I've tried it on so far, but there is a situation where I want it to be very large so I tried to use `zoom: n%`.

This worked great in all browsers except FireFox, which apparently doesn't support the zoom style. I have to use `-moz-transform: scale(n)` instead.

The problem is that this is really caddywhompus and all kinds of weird. I can't seem to figure out how to get the effect I'm aiming for - I just want to make the checkbox bigger, but the scale property keeps changing its location, positioning, hit box, etc.

this is a jsbin that demonstrates the issue in FireFox
http://jsbin.com/rawokixoya/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Except if I'm doing something wrong, the checkbox is showing the same result on both Chrome and Firefox. (Clicking it, changes it to the blue V, and back to box when you click again). - Edit: hitbox and positioning are the same as well for me.